# dhtmlxGrid Suite serialize returning sub_row data as part of userData

Tags: dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxSuite 4.6 PRO version. I have a situation where I need to serialize all rows of the grid along with userData. I have used the following method to make sure I get userdata:

```
myGrid.setSerializationLevel(true,false,false,false,false,true);
```

I am also using sub_row column type for one of my column. When I use the following to serialize grid data:

```
myGrid.serialize()
```

then I get serialized XML along with userData but it is also returning sub_row data as part part of userData as '_sub_row'

Is there a way to remove 'sub_row' or selectively pick what all userData values are needed for serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the known issue. It was fixed in 5.0 version. Please, try to update your dhtmlx package.